# How to extract ViewContainerRef and ComponentRef in most efficient way?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-material2

I work with angular-material mdSidenav and want to programmatically open it and insert custom component.

I use `@ViewChild('varName')` to extract componentInstance and `@ViewChild('varName', {read: ViewContainerRef})` to extract container where I would place my content.

So, my question is - is it possible just 1 @ViewChild and get other info from extracted reference.

Second question - which values allowed for read property ? ElementRef/ViewContainerRef/... ?

Update:

I found, that ViewContainerRef of mdSidenav incorrect container for my component. How to place component.hostView inside mdSidenav hostView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible just 1 @ViewChild and get other info from extracted
>   reference.

No, you can't specify multiple read types for one property. For example you specify the following in html:

```
<ng-template mydir #vc></ng-template>
```

Now it can be read as `ElementRef`, `TemplateRef`, `ViewContainerRef` or `MyDirectiveInstance`. You can't specify multiple `read` types because Angular would not know what to return for this node. You have to specify single `read` type for each query property. And generally you can't get one type from the other. Although both

> Which values allowed for read property ?
>   ElementRef/ViewContainerRef/... ?

There are the following types you can get through query:

- ElementRef
- TemplateRef
- ViewContainerRef
- Provider (Component/Directive instance)

As can be seen from this source code:

```
export function getQueryValue(
    view: ViewData, nodeDef: NodeDef, queryValueType: QueryValueType): any {
  if (queryValueType != null) {
    // a match
    let value: any;
    switch (queryValueType) {
      case QueryValueType.RenderElement:
        value = asElementData(view, nodeDef.index).renderElement;
        break;
      case QueryValueType.ElementRef:
        value = new ElementRef(asElementData(view, nodeDef.index).renderElement);
        break;
      case QueryValueType.TemplateRef:
        value = asElementData(view, nodeDef.index).template;
        break;
      case QueryValueType.ViewContainerRef:
        value = asElementData(view, nodeDef.index).viewContainer;
        break;
      case QueryValueType.Provider:
        value = asProviderData(view, nodeDef.index).instance;
        break;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

`RenderElement` points to the native DOM element associated with the view node but it is used internally and AFAIK can't be accessed using query in the component.