# Get DOM element which is a component in Angular

Tags: angular

I read some answers already here, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template), but my problem is slightly different. I want to get component as a DOM element so that I can add/remove some CSS classes on it.

My HTML template contains component:

`<sidenav-menu #sidenav class="app__sidenav"></sidenav-menu>`

And my class contains a reference to it:

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: ElementRef;
```

But when I log `this.sidenav` in one of my functions, I see that it is a representation of a class of Sidenav component, not its DOM representation. Why is that happening?

Comment: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45064618/2545680) for reference what can be passed to `{read:...}` parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify what you want using the `read` parameter:

```ts
@ViewChild('sidenav', {read: ElementRef}) sidenav: ElementRef;
```

This way you get the `ElementRef` and can use `this.sidenav.nativeElement` like mentioned by @joshrathke

or (for other use cases)

```ts
@ViewChild('sidenav', {read: ViewContainerRef}) sidenav: ElementRef;
```

My answer to the question you liked to also mentions this `read` parameter https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/217408

Comment: @TheOpti glad to hear :-)

Comment: Wouldn't a more "Angular-y" way to do this be using the `ngClass` directive?

Comment: @DeborahK I looked at the question again but I can't find information about what the actual intention was. You might be right. I just pointed out what struck me what can't work and how to fix it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the info. Wasn't sure if I was just missing something. Yea ... sometimes when there is not enough info its hard to drill down to what they are really trying to do and suggest alternatives vs just answering what they are asking..

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

In order for this to work, you need to implement @Günter Zöchbauer suggestion for extracting the component using `ViewChild` with `read`.

**Original Answer**

You need to use the `nativeElement` property of the `ElementRef` object. You'll find your DOM Representation there. Its also what exposes the DOM element and allows you to call traditional methods on it as if it was a DOM element in vanilla javascript or jQuery.

```js
console.log(this.sidenav.nativeElement);
```

Comment: That doesn't work, if the element is component, the component instance is injected. Adding `:ElementRef` has no effect.

Comment: Agree, that does not work - I do not have such property when I log this.sidenav

Comment: Ahh, You're right. I missed that completely.Thank you for the clarification @GünterZöchbauer.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the post to refer to your post @GünterZöchbauer, thanks for the correction.